# Slow loading Datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datagridview

I load the result of the sql-query into a DatagridView using Entity Framework Model First.

I know that this method is wrong, but this method was shown at my university. How do I optimize data loading? Should I build DataTable? Less than 1000 records are loaded in 5-7 seconds.

```cs
IVCEntities db = new IVCEntities();
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter nnar = 
new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@nnar", NumNaryd);
var view = db.Database.SqlQuery<Reestr>("select  * from Reestr where Status <> 'Printed' and NumNar = @nnar ", nnar);
foreach (var v in view)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
                row.CreateCells(dgvView);
                row.Cells[0].Value = v.NumNar.ToString().Substring(5));
                row.Cells[1].Value = v.TabNum;
                row.Cells[2].Value = v.Status;
                row.Cells[3].Value = v.Detal;
                row.Cells[4].Value = v.DateForm.ToShortDateString();
                row.Cells[5].Value = v.Naladchik;
                dgvView.Rows.Add(row);
            }
```

Comment: @TaW, sorry, `view` - SQLQuery

Comment: You can collect the rows to add and use [AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.addrange?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewRowCollection_AddRange_System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewRow___) to add them all in one go. But in general, yes, Filling the data into a DataTable and binding to it is the recommended was.

Comment: Speed is based on the size of the database and the amount of data transfer between the database and c#.  Without knowing the sizes it is hard to determine if the time is due to the DGV loading.  Without making sure it is not the database size or amount of data transferred I'm not assuming anything.  The datatable in SQL could have 10,000 columns and still returning 1000 records and the database could have 100,000,000 records.

Comment: @TaW, Im so sorry for my stupid questions but can you suggest me. How I can bind result of sqlQuery `view` and DataTable?

Comment: No, you would first `Fill` a DataTable!

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
dgvView.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.EnableResizing;
```

if it still loading slowly better to use

```
dgvView.RowHeadersWidthSizeMode = DataGridViewRowHeadersWidthSizeMode.DisableResizing;
```

And use:

```
dgvView.RowHeadersVisible = false;
```

you can re-enable the above feature after data is bound :

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: So please try following, must work
dgvView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
dgvView.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.DisableResizing;